# Android MenuItem in ActionBar with Icon and Text. How to align icon to right?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, menuitem, arabic

I would like to place the icon in my MenuItem to right side. It's normally on the left side and then is the text on the left. I'm doing app for arabic and I would prefer to align this icon on right

[image]

to something like this style:

[image]

Edited:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- Single menu item
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_donate"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_dollar"
      android:title="@string/donate"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings" 
      android:title="@string/menu_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logout"
      android:title="@string/signout" 
      app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? And What you are getting currently? @Michal Ziobro

Comment: nothing special I'm just using standard menu resource with <menu> and <item> and consider whether there is easy way to do this...

Comment: But what you are getting when you change your device locale to Arabic? @Michal Ziobro

Comment: IIRC for layouts there are options "align on beginning" and "align on end" which behave as "align left" or "align right" based on the writing direction. Did you try them? What did you get?

Comment: I have set arabic localization, android:layout_gravity="start" doesn't work I think because there isn't differentiation to item icon item label in Menu Item i think

Comment: @MichałZiobro Screen shot will help us to understand that what behavior you are getting when you change locale to Arabic.